# Publishing MVC4 to release

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2015, publish

I am stumbling from article to article but I am missing the overall picture.
I hope you can give me some advice on publishing a release package.

My project and environment:

- Project: MVC4 with VS2015
- JS libraries included with NuGet (including full.js and .min.js versions)
- All JS packages are defined as bundles in the BundeConfig class
- My angular code is included with a Bundle that includes the whole \App folder.
- less files are compiled with Web Compiler extention

When I use the publish wizard with release profile I get all the files of the project but I'd like to have:

- no less files at all
- only .min.js files and no full.js files for the NuGet packages
- not my complete angular code but only a bundled/minified version
- my css files as a single bundled/minified version

When I use the debug profile, the files should be unbundled/unminified.

What I've read so far there may be a solution using changes in .wpp.targets file, .pubxml file, web.config file or .csproj file. Some of the blogs mention code snippets, but I do not know where to put them exactely.

Am I heading to the right direction or is there a completely other best practice way? Thanks for helping!

Some of my references:
http://sedodream.com/2010/08/15/WebDeploymentToolMSDeployHowToExcludeFilesFromPackageBasedOnConfiguration.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee942158(v=vs.110).aspx#can_i_exclude_specific_files_or_folders_from_deployment

Comment: Why would you need to do this? Are you trying to save  disk space?

Comment: It seems to be cleaner not having developer stuff in the release package. The fully commented source code is not for public viewing anyway.